# How can I use routerlink to change the url and not the component?

Tags: angular, navigation, routerlink

I have a service that records page activity with the `NavigationEnd` event from `router.events`

Am I able to change the url without changing/displaying new children components?

Right now I have

```
{
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '**', component: DummyRoutingComponent}   
    ]
}
```

DummyRoutingComponent displays nothing.

This way I can `routerLink="what-ever-I-want"` and have it get recorded by my service. I realize this has some issues if the page were to grow more.

Is there a better way to achieve my results?

Comment: You have a service that records route activity, but at the sametime all your routes display a dummy component. Please explain what would be the point of recording such meaningless activity?

Comment: @cgTag My code is general here, this is one portion of the app, I should have made that more clear within the question.

the dummy routes are used in this part of the app (something like `app/(section)/(area)/**` the `**` represents route changes but no component changes. I know i could add service calls and manual add the activity recording but if it's possible similar to how im doing it now it's really convenient.